# couchbase, ottoman throw error when I create a new instance?

Tags: node.js, model, schema, couchbase, couchbase-ottoman

I'm new in couchbase and I'm using ottoman framework. I connected the database using ottoman and I create the schema and model `User` and exported it into controller file. When I create a new instance for that model, ottoman throw an error `TypeError: User is not a constructor`.

I search so many time and I red the official and non official documents and test it severely. I wrote all about the db in separate file and no change. I'll attach the file below it . But I didn't get any solution. please let me know...

```js
const ottoman = require("ottoman");

exports.connect = async () => {
  try {
    await ottoman.connect({
      connectionString: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING,
      bucketName: process.env.DB_BUCKET,
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    });
    console.log("Database connected.");
    await ottoman.start();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Database not connected due to: ", error.message);
  }
};

connect();

const User = ottoman.model("User", {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  tagline: String,
});

const perry = new User({
  firstName: "Perry",
  lastName: "Mason",
  email: "perry.mason@example.com",
  tagLine: "Who can we get on the case?",
});

const tom = new User({
  firstName: "Major",
  lastName: "Tom",
  email: "major.tom@example.com",
  tagLine: "Send me up a drink",
});

main = async () => {
  await perry.save();
  console.log(`success: user ${perry.firstName} added!`);

  await tom.save();
  console.log(`success: user ${tom.firstName} added!`);
};

main();
```

Comment: What version of Ottoman are you using?

Comment: @MatthewGroves version 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened due to disorder of functions calling in `app.js` file. All I used till now was a Mongodb and mongoose in noSQL. In the case of mongodb we can call the database config function after api endpoint specification. I wrote my code like this in couchbase. But it didn't stick in couchbase. I'll provide my code before and after fixing for more clarity, and I'm very sorry for my bad english. :)

Before fixing `app.js` file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// routes
app.use("/api/", require("./routes/index"));

// bad requiest
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: "Bad Requist." });
});

// error middleware
const { errorHandler } = require("./middlewares/error-middleware");
app.use(errorHandler);

// database setup
const db = require("./config/db");
db.connect();


// server setup
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(`The server is running on: ${PORT}.`);
  }
});
```

After fixing `app.js` file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// database setup
const db = require("./config/db");
db.connect();

// routes
app.use("/api/", require("./routes/index"));

// bad requiest
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: "Bad Requist." });
});

// error middleware
const { errorHandler } = require("./middlewares/error-middleware");
app.use(errorHandler);

// server setup
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(`The server is running on: ${PORT}.`);
  }
});
```